# pickerInput choices does not align all to the same side

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, pickerinput

I am using "pickerInput" in Shiny with six options to choose from. The first four options align to the left and the icon to the right, but the fifth option aligns everything to the left and the sixth option aligns everything to the right as seen in the image.

[image]

I leave the code of the options in the pickerInput:

```
list(`style` = "btn-warning",
                 `actions-box` = TRUE,
                 `deselect-all-text` = "Ninguno",
                 `select-all-text` = "Todos",
                 `selected-text-format` = "count > 0",
                 `dropdown-align-center` = TRUE,
                 `count-selected-text` = "Filtro {0} de {1} años",
                 `none-selected-text` = "Ningún año filtrado"
)
```

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)